# multiple virtual inheritance in C++ complains on specific function call

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, ambiguous

In C++ multiple inheritance with virtual base
 i understand why could this code be ambiguous , but why it still complains when i specifically call a derived class method ?

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << 1 ;}
};
class B :virtual public A {
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << 2; }
};
class C :virtual public A {
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << 3; }
};
class D : public B, public C {};

void main(){
    D* d = new D();
    d->B::f();
    getch();
}
```

i would expect that it will run the B:f() method but i get  :
"ambiguous inheritance of 'void A::f(void)'

Comment: You are experiencing what is known as the `Diamond Inheritance Problem`..  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem

Comment: That fact that you try to call that specific function doesn't fix the D class itself.

Comment: @OP, I just thought I'd point this out.. `main` in C and C++ is NEVER `void`. Please change it to return `int`. It really bothers me seeing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function is virtual which means it overrides address in vtable. You can't override one address with two functions.
Without `virtual` qualifier there would be just ambiguity during the call which can be avoided just like you did specifying base class `B::f()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your class D has two final overriders of function f. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual about final overrider.